# Repeat AsyncTask on the next code

Tags: android, android-asynctask, refresh

I have a code that only takes information from a web vía Jsoup and I want to refresh this information every second. I tried with all the code that I've found in Google and stackoverflow with no luck. Thank you very much in advance. [SOLVED]

Now I'm trying to send an array from MainActivity to another Activity called "Activity_allday" with Bundle and Intent when viewallday() function is called pressing the "btviewallday" button but with no luck. Any suggestions?

LogCat error: Could not find a method viewallday(View) in the activity class com.example.Chispa.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btviewallday'.

I've noticed that the error comes from receiving two values at viewallday(View view, Pair p). How can I receive the "Pair p" value in my viewallday function?

Here is the new app code:

[MainActivity]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView tvmax, tvmid, tvmin, tvactualval,tvvaloractual,tvdate;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvdate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvdate);
        tvvaloractual=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvvaloractual);
        tvmax=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvmaximo);
        tvmid=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvmedio);
        tvmin=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvminimo);

        new BackGroundTask().execute();

        callAsynchronousTask();

    }


    public void callAsynchronousTask() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {       
                        try {
                            BackGroundTask performBackgroundTask = new BackGroundTask();
                            // PerformBackgroundTask this class is the class that extends AsynchTask 
                            performBackgroundTask.execute();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 1000); //execute in every 1000 ms
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class Pair
    {
        public String[] bar;
        public String[] values;
    }



    public void viewallday(View view, Pair p) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_allday.class);

        Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
        bundle.putStringArray("bar", p.bar);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);

    }



    class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Pair> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }


        public String[] getValuesGraph(Document doc) {


                int cont=24,var=7;
                String bar[] = new String[cont];



               /*
                * Getting elements from the graphic in an array from 0-23. 0 it's 1:00am, 23 it's 00:00am
                */

               for (cont=0; cont < 24; cont++){

               String onMouseOver = doc.select("a").get(var+cont).attr("onMouseOver");
               bar[cont] = onMouseOver.split("'")[9];


               }


               return bar;



        }



        public String[] getValuesFooter(Document doc) {



            String values[] = new String[7];


            /*
                * Getting elements from the graphic footer
                */

               String delimiters= "[ /]+";
               Elements elements = doc.select("td.cabeceraRutaTexto");
               elements.size(); // 6



                   /*  Getting text from table */
                   values[0] = elements.get(0).text(); // TITLE
                   values[1] = elements.get(1).text(); // TEXT MAX VALUE
                   values[2] = elements.get(2).text(); // TEXT MIDDLE VALUE
                   values[3] = elements.get(3).text(); // TEXTO MIN VALUE

                   /* Getting numbers from table */

                   values[4] = elements.get(4).text().split(delimiters)[0]; // NUMBER MAX VALUE
                   values[5] = elements.get(5).text().split(delimiters)[0]; // NUMBER MIDDLE VALUE
                   values[6] = elements.get(6).text().split(delimiters)[0]; // NUMBER MIN VALUE    


                   return values;


         }




        @Override
        public Pair doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Pair p = new Pair();


            try {

                URL url= new URL("http://www.myweb.com");
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url.toString()).get();

                p.bar = getValuesGraph(doc);

                p.values = getValuesFooter(doc);

               /*
                * Getting elements from the graphic in an array from 0-23. 0 it's 1:00am, 23 it's 00:00am
                */


         return p;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }



        public String ActualHourValue() {

            Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("H");
            String onlyhour = formatter.format(new Date());

            return onlyhour;


        }

        public void ShowDateHour(){


            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
            String formattedDate3 = df3.format(c.getTime());
            tvdate.setText("Fecha y hora actuales : "+formattedDate3);

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Pair p) {


            int hour =  Integer.parseInt(ActualHourValue());
            tvvaloractual.setText(p.bar[hour]+" €/MWh");

            tvmax.setText(p.values[4]+" €/MWh");
            tvmid.setText(p.values[5]+" €/MWh");
            tvmin.setText(p.values[6]+" €/MWh");

            ShowDateHour();

           /*super.onPostExecute(p.values);*/
        }




    }




}
```

[Activity_allday]

```
Public class Activity_allday extends MainActivity {

private TextView tvall;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_day_prices);

    tvall = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvall);

    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] bar=bundle.getStringArray("bar");
    /*tvall.setText(bar[0]);*/
}

public void back (View view) {
    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: Are you calling `callAsynchronousTask` anywhere?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and time. You're totally right. I'm not calling the function anywhere!

Comment: The app It's now doing what I wanted. I'm totally newbie at Java and Android, hope this code helps someone.

I call the callAsynchronousTask from onCreate(), under new BackGroundTask().execute();. It's the best place to call it from? @Nicholas

Comment: I haven't used `Timer` at all. However quickly looking at the docs, I think it depends. You may want to put it in on `onResume`, and possibly cancel the `timer` in `onPause`. You may want to do some further checking to see if the timer still runs when you minimise your app, and if that's what you really want. Also, what happens if screen orientation changes, do you end up with multiple timers running?

Comment: You should also assume that the response to your http request will come back in more than one second.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your comments and clarifications. I'm learning a lot. Finally the code works calling callAsynchronousTask() from onCreate().

Now I'm trying to send an array from MainActivity to another Activity with Bundle and Intent but with no luck. Any suggestions? I'm going to update the previous code with my new code. I receive the next error:

Comment: Could not find a method viewallday(View) in the activity class com.example.Chispa.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btviewallday'